# Process JSON data to form input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, each

I've got a jQuery Ajax response with JSON data that I need to process and having problems with. Each JSON "key" represents a form input field name attribute which it's associated data needs to go in to.

Currently my jQuery Ajax success function has the following which doesn't work...

```
success: function(data) {

  if(data.Status == "Success"){

     $.each(data, function(key,value){
        $("input[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
     );

  }else{
    // Error stuff
  }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.... I'm pulling my hair out here over something which I'm sure should be quite simple.

Dan

Comment: What is `data.Status`, and why would you iterate over `data` if it includes a `Status` property?

Comment: Print with `console.log` the (key, value) pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code: (you missed a `}`)

```
success: function(data) {

  if(data.Status == "Success"){

     $.each(data, function(key,value){
        $("input[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
     }); // here you made mistake

  }else{
    // Error stuff
  }
}
```

If the above code not working, please use `console.log` in Google Chrome and see the values for `key` and `value` pair from `each` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If response is actually a JSON string instead of a real JS Object, you should use jQuery.parseJSON(data) to actually turn it into a JS object first before using it, iterating over it, etc.